# Cannot use downcast Any to an array containing references

Tags: rust

Passing just an array seems to work fine:

```
fn set_zero<'a>(u: &'a u32, ms: &mut [Option<&'a u32>; 4]) {
    ms[0] = Some(u);
}
```

I'm trying to wrap C callback function which is passed a `void *`
so I'm using `std::any::Any` instead of an array:

```
fn set_zero<'a>(u: &'a u32, ma: &mut Any) {
    if let Some(ms) = ma.downcast_mut::<[Option<&'a u32>; 4]>() {
        ms[0] = Some(u);
    }
}
```

This causes an error related to lifetimes:

```
error[E0477]: the type `[std::option::Option<&'a u32>; 4]` 
does not fulfill the required lifetime
--> option.rs:18:26
   |
18 |     if let Some(ms) = ma.downcast_mut::<[Option<&'a u32>; 4]>() {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
  = note: type must outlive the static lifetime
```

How can I fix this? What documentation should read to understand the error better?

**UPDATE**: more detailed background:

An contrived C prototype is - foo.c:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int (*cb_t)(const uint32_t *obj, void *arg);

int32_t cb_run(uint32_t const objs[], uint32_t len, cb_t cb, void *arg)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
                if (cb(&objs[i], arg) < 0)
                        return -1;
        return 0;
}
```

Then, I tried to wrap by using `Any`:

```
extern crate libc;
use libc::{c_int, size_t, c_void};
use std::any::Any;

type CbT = extern "C" fn(obj: *const u32, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int;
extern { fn cb_run(objs: *const u32, len: size_t, cb: CbT, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int; }

type Cb = fn(obj: &u32, arg: &mut Any) -> i32;
struct CbData <'a> {
    cb: Cb,
    arg: &'a mut Any,
}

extern fn rust_cb(obj: *const u32, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int {
    unsafe {
        let s = &mut *(arg as *mut CbData);
        (s.cb)(&*obj, s.arg)
    }
}

fn cb_run_rs(objs: &[u32], cb: Cb, arg: &mut Any) -> i32 {
    let mut arg = &mut CbData{ cb: cb, arg: arg } ;
    unsafe { cb_run(objs.as_ptr() as *const u32, objs.len() as size_t,
                    rust_cb, arg as *mut _ as *mut c_void) as i32 }
}

//// the above is lib, the below is bin

// set_zero() in the above
fn my_cb<'a>(obj: &'a u32, arg: &mut Any) -> i32 {
    if let Some(data) = arg.downcast_mut::<[Option<&'a u32>; 4]>() {
        data[0] = Some(obj);
    }
    0
}

fn main() {
    let objs = [0u32, 1, 2, 3];
    let mut arg = [None; 4];
    println!("pre  : {:?}", arg);
    cb_run_rs(&objs, my_cb, &mut arg);
    println!("post : {:?}", arg);
}
```

And it causes `note: type must outlive the static lifetime`.
How can I handle this kind of `void *` in good manner without `unsafe` from library user?

Comment: `Any` is not a reasonable equivalent of `void *`

Comment: Anyway, read the first paragraph of [the `Any` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html) again: *which enables dynamic typing of **any `'static` type** through runtime reflection.* — your type isn't static.

Comment: It's just as you say. I realize I misunderstood a `'static` is a type that is known at compile time. Can I think it as one of the reasons for `Any` is not a reasonable equivalent of `void *`?

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell it seems to work. main.rs

```
extern crate libc;
use libc::{c_int, size_t, c_void};

type CbT = extern "C" fn(obj: *const u32, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int;
extern { fn cb_run(objs: *const u32, len: size_t, cb: CbT, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int; }

type Cb <'a, T: ?Sized> = fn(obj: &'a u32, arg: &mut T) -> i32;
struct CbData <'a, 'b, T: 'a + 'b + ?Sized> {
    cb: Cb<'a, T>,
    arg: &'b mut T,
}

extern fn rust_cb<T: ?Sized>(obj: *const u32, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int {
    unsafe {
        let s = &mut *(arg as *mut CbData<T>);
        (s.cb)(&*obj, s.arg)
    }
}

fn cb_run_rs<'a, 'b, T: 'a + ?Sized>(objs: &[u32], cb: Cb<'a, T>, arg: &'b mut T) -> i32 {
    let mut arg = &mut CbData{ cb: cb, arg: arg } ;
    unsafe { cb_run(objs.as_ptr() as *const u32, objs.len() as size_t,
                    rust_cb::<T>, arg as *mut _ as *mut c_void) as i32 }
}

//// the above is lib, the below is bin

fn my_cb<'a>(obj: &'a u32, arg: &mut [Option<&'a u32>]) -> i32 {
    arg[*obj as usize] = Some(obj);
    0
}

fn main() {
    let objs = [0u32, 1, 2, 3];
    let mut arg = [None; 4];
    println!("pre  : {:?}", arg);
    cb_run_rs(&objs, my_cb, &mut arg);
    println!("post : {:?}", arg);
}
```

FYI build.rs:

```
extern crate gcc;

fn main() {
    gcc::compile_library("libfoo.a", &["src/foo.c"]);
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "sof"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["author@example.com"]
build = "build.rs"

[build-dependencies]
gcc = "0.3"

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"
```